# Javascript RegExp Curly Brace and test Issue

Tags: javascript

I want regExp to test for two 'Hello'-s and return true but it only returns false even though I cannot find anything wrong with my code. How do I fix this? Please also suggest what is wrong with the code.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var str ="Hello Hello";
var patt = /(hello){2}/gi;
var result =patt.test(str);
document.write("Returned value: " + result); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the space:

```
var patt = /(hello ?){2}/gi;
```

Your original RE matches "HelloHello", but not two occurences of "Hello".

Comment: Thanks mate. I totally forgot about the space. And I thought that hellohello is the thing but I forgot the space. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `match()` method which searches for a match between a regular expression and a string, and returns the matches.

```
   var result = "Hello hello".match(/Hello/gi); // Array { 0="Hello", 1="hello"}

   result.length // 2
```

If you want to use search instead of match:

```
   "hello hello ".search(/(hello ?){2}/gi); // it returns 0 when it find two occurrences of hello
                                            // if not it returns -1
```